How to set default of Gantt in Deneb-Vega to "ALL" instead of "Days"
I'm using the incredible Gantt chart by David Bacci and have pretty much got it configured to how I need for the team I'm building it for. The one thing that would be really helpful is if my default view was to "All" instead of days. Our projects are really long so when it defaults to days it's hard to understand where the task is in comparison with other phases or projects.
If doing this requires getting rid of the "Days" option altogether that's totally fine as well, the tooltip with the dates serves that purpose just as well for our needs.
I tried doing something similar to the "hacky" solution he gave here: How to Set Default Collapsed State in Deneb-Vega Gantt Chart for Power BI
But I'm just not experienced enough to know if this should work or where to put it.
Thanks in advance!

I uploaded a new version 2 days ago with a config option that allows you to set the start granularity. Get the latest version and you'll be all set.

Wow thanks so much! You're right, this is exactly what I needed.
For other's that may be looking: New code starting on line 33 for "startGrain"
